# UK Landing Card

Tags: united-kingdom

I will be arriving in the UK next week on a one year graduate program. I will be staying at a hotel the first couple of days then move into my student accommodation. With regards to the UK landing card, where asked about a UK address, should I declare the hotel I am staying at, at first, or my student accommodation as that will be my address for the rest of the year?

Comment: Do you have the address of your student accommodation ? Anyway give your hotel accommodation initially and when the officer queries explain the situation.

Comment: @DumbCoder yes I do have the address of my student accommodation. I have already paid for the fees for my entire stay (51 weeks).

Comment: I think you should list the address of your student accommodation and not of the place where you plan to stay for only 2 days.  If asked you can explain your hotel stay